# problem uploading a django project to AWS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hello I am trying to put my django's project to AWS.

I have done the following things the tutorial
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-configure-for-eb)

Mi configuration file **django.config** is:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: ebdjango.wsgi:application


container_commands:
  01_postgresql:
    command: sudo yum -y install gcc python-setuptools python-devel postgresql-devel
  02_postgresql:
    command: sudo easy_install psycopg2
```

I create an enviroment (**eb create django-env1**). Then it says me the following thing when I do (**eb status**).

```
Environment details for: django-env1
  Region: us-west-2
  Deployed Version: app-b7ea-210708_181635
  Environment ID: e-ax2b7ff3bb
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-2::platform/Python 2.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.15
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: django-env1.eba-b3pwjnx2.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com
  Updated: 2021-07-08 16:19:37.455000+00:00
  Status: Ready
  Health: Green
Alert: Your environment is using a retired platform branch. It's no longer supported.
```

I don't know why because I don't why.

Thank you

Comment: Bad I can't solve my problem. I am trying to update the WSGIPath with eb config but It doesn't work

Comment: Did you upgrade to new platform as I wrote?

Comment: My eb health is red

Comment: Yes, I solved this problem but now I have another one ..

Comment: If you want to colaborate more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68365462/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-application-error-in-aws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Python 2.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.15` which is no longer supported. You have to use something that is [supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.python), such as

```
64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.3.2 running Python 3.8
```