# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application' error in AWS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy a Django app to AWS.

I am getting the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'" when I try to create the app (with `django create django-env`). I don't know why.

My django.config file:

```
option_settings:
"aws:elasticbeanstalk:projectlication:environment":
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: project.settings
"aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
WSGIPath: project.wsgi:application
```

The layout of my application:

[image: screenshot of directory]

My application name is "project", so I don't know what is wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post layout of your application?

Comment: ok, I will update this post

Comment: You say me if you need more information. I am a new contributor

Comment: I am trying to solve the problem with the command eb config and changing WSGIPath

Comment: Did you follow this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) from AWS docs?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I have this problem

Comment: I am tying to change the configuration with eb config and change WSGIPath, but I don't know what to write instead application

Comment: How are you deploying the application, is it via the EB CLI or are you uploading a zip file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a wild guess based on the little information you've given but I would check that the WSGIPath points to your django applications `wsgi.py` file.

Again, I'm just guessing because you haven't provided much context. The following might be of some help [Deploying Django + Python 3 + PostgreSQL to AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://realpython.com/deploying-a-django-app-and-postgresql-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/#configuring-our-python-environment)

Edit: edited because I can't read.

Comment: Hello, my django's project name is project. So I have updated **eb config** , now WSGI is WSGIPath: project/project/wsgi:application. But **eb status** say that health is red. I don't know why. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Git, After making changes on settings.py and wsgi.py please remember to Commit the changes.
When we execute eb deploy, it builds and deploy the application only with the files that are committed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).